# Can I be sure that a UDP recv executed immediately after a successfull call to recv with MSG_PEEK will not block?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, recv

Assume the following code (for the sake of simplicity I’ve omitted the necessary error handling here):

```
recv(sockfd, NULL, 0, MSG_PEEK);
recv(sockfd, buff, bufflen, 0);
```

In that case: Can I be sure that after the first call to `recv` the whole datagram is already received and therefore the second call to to `recv` will not block?

Or can it happen that if IP splits the datagram, the first `recv` returns as soon as any part of this datagram is received, and the second `recv` will block until the whole datagram is received?

If I substitute the first call to `recv` with:

```
recv(sockfd, NULL, 0, MSG_PEEK | MSG_TRUNC);
```

Can I be sure that this will only return once the whole datagram is received, since otherwise it would be no way for `recv` to reliably return the length of the whole datagram, as requested by `MSG_TRUNC`?

Comment: Not if there's another process or thread with an FD for the same socket. It could read the packet before you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I be sure that after the first call to recv the whole datagram is
>   already received and therefore the second call to to recv will not
>   block?

A UDP socket operates in whole-datagram units.  The first call will not return until a datagram is available, unless it returns -1 to indicate an error.  (A TCP socket might return 0 to signal closure of the connection, but that will not happen with a UDP, since it's connectionless.)

@Barmar observes in comments that another thread or processwith access to the same socket could, in principle, read that waiting datagram before the one that called the first `recv()` does, but if that's not a concern for you then the subsequent `recv()` indeed should return the whole datagram, up to the amount of space available in the buffer (any excess bytes in the message are lost).  Of course this begs the question of why you want to do this -- you might as well have skipped the first `recv()`, and let the second one block if necessary.

Adding `MSG_TRUNC` to the flags doesn't alter any of the above.  Again, a UDP socket operates in whole-datagram units.  The only difference is that the return value gives you the size of the datagram.  *That* could be a reason for the extra `recv()` call.

Comment: Why such a construct? I have two threads, one repeatedly doing only `recv` and the other repeatedly only `send`, for the sole purpose of letting them do their job w/o having to wait till the other one's blocking socket call returns. For the sake of simplicity, I wanted to do the second `recv` under a mutex protecting common data locked, so that this second `recv` can write to this common data. If this second `recv` doesn't block, it's fine. If it could block, then the whole idea wouldn't make much sense.